# Image from assets not found in scss

Tags: css, angular

First; I saw similar questions, however, they don't contain a valid solution for me, tried all of them and they were not working.

The thing I want to achieve is really simple, I just want to put a background image in CSS, but I receive an error `image not found`.

Using image from assets in HTML like:
`<img src="assets/images/news-placeholder.png" alt="news-image" />`
works pretty fine.

Approach `url('/assets/images/wallpaper.jpg')` in CSS works, but only on localhost, when deployed on the server the image is not found as there is no `assets` folder in root directory and that's my problem. Also the IDE (PhpStorm) says that it can't resolve `assets` directory even if the image shows up.

I found out, that this approach: `url('assets/images/wallpaper.jpg')`, is the best, but when I use it there is an error at localhost, that it can't resolve image in path of component, eg. `/src/app/modules/portal/components/page-header`

Comment: What about adding img by URL instead of your local directory?

Comment: remove the single quotes :  `url(assets/images/wallpaper.jpg)` in css, also make sure that you have set correct base for your app

Answer (score 1):

If your app is deployed anywhere else than the host's root path, i.e. `www.example.com/apps/myApp` instead of `www.example.com`, it needs to be built with appropriate `--base-href` flag, like this:

`ng build --prod --base-href /apps/myApp`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the assets folder inside the build option in angular.json like this.

"`assets`": [
 "`src/favicon.ico`",
          "`src/assets`"
            ]